How Can I Implement Reliable Background Song Transitions Using Spotify SDK?
I’m building a music streaming app that integrates with Spotify, and I’m facing issues with implementing background song transitions for a configurable playlist. Each song in the playlist has a stored start second and a specific duration, and the app is supposed to transition to the next song when the current one reaches its configured duration.
The Problem
In the foreground, transitions work perfectly—each song starts at its configured second and transitions after the specific duration.
In the background, songs continue playing until their full duration because the transition method (e.g., Schedule Next Song) doesn’t get called.
What I’ve Tried
Using DispatchQueue:
I’ve tried scheduling transitions on DispatchQueue.main and DispatchQueue.global() with delayed execution, but neither approach works consistently in the background.
Discussion Questions
How can I reliably schedule and execute song transitions in the background while streaming with Spotify SDK?
Are there better approaches to handling scheduled tasks in iOS that work consistently in the background?
private func scheduleNextSong(remindDuration: TimeInterval? = nil) async {
            let nextIndex = currentQueueIndex + 1
            let songQueueItem = songQueue[currentQueueIndex]
            let duration = remindDuration ?? TimeInterval(songQueueItem.songDuration)
    
            guard nextIndex < songQueue.count else {
                playNextSongWorkItem?.cancel()
                playNextSongWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                    self.sendToFlutterLastSong() // Notify Flutter that the last song has played
                }
                if let playNextSongWorkItem = playNextSongWorkItem {
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration, execute: playNextSongWorkItem)
                }
                return
            }
    
            // Cancel any existing work items to prevent overlapping
            playNextSongWorkItem?.cancel()
            playNextSongWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                self.currentQueueIndex += 1
                Task { await self.playCurrentSongQueue() }
            }
    
            if let playNextSongWorkItem = playNextSongWorkItem {
                DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration, execute: playNextSongWorkItem)
            }
        }


When your app is not onscreen you can't rely in any Timer or similar construct, including asyncAfter; your app is suspended and only receives execution time for specific background modes, such as supplying audio data. Spotify support for cross fade is built into the api.  Can't you use that?
